# Why can the posix thread id be NULL in Linux kernel function filp_close?

Tags: linux, file, linux-kernel, posix

Below is excerpted from linux kernel:

```
/*
 * "id" is the POSIX thread ID. We use the
 * files pointer for this..
 */
int filp_close(struct file *filp, fl_owner_t id)
```

The documentation says `id` is the posix thread id, and it should be `current->files`.

However, I found many usages in Linux kernel, e.g. [acct_on](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/kernel/acct.c#L212), use it as `filp_close(filp, NULL)`

**My questions are:**

Why is NULL acceptable when calling `filp_close`?

What is the intent of the argument `id`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this [discussion](http://www.gossamer-threads.com/lists/linux/kernel/1999733), formal description of `fl_owner_t` would be

```
A generic "file lock owner" value. This is set differently for different 
types of locks. 

The POSIX file lock owner is determined by the "struct files_struct" in the 
thread group. 

Flock (BSD) locks, OFD locks and leases set the fl_owner to the 
file description pointer.
```

but actually this is opaque pointer

```
legacy typedef, should eventually go away
```

which refers to process file descriptor table (`struct files_struct`).

As for `filp_close` function, only `fs/file.c` source uses non-NULL `id` parameter. All other users create `filp` by hands (using `filp_open` or `file_open_name`) and pass `id` as NULL.